# Vertx STOMP session stores configuration

Tags: session, stomp, vert.x

I'm using [Vertx-STOMP](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-stomp/java/) over websockets and I have followed the instructions from the documentation with success.

My question is how is it possible to enable session store in order to utilize it in my application? I cannot find any obvious example.

Am I on the right direction if I try to enable Session with instructions from the [vertx-web](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_handling_sessions)?

Moreover, is it possible to maintain both stomp server and http server to serve normal RESTful requests under different endpoints, for instance:

> WEBSOCKET STOMP via /stomp

and

> RESTful API via /api/*

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly you're looking into using your STOMP server to store the session data for your application. If that is the case, you're out of luck since there is currently 2 implementations:

- Local Storage (in memory)
- Clustered Storage (using the underlying cluster manager)

See here: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/tree/master/vertx-web/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/web/sstore

If you really need a custom storage and you're willing to contribute to the open source project I'd say provide an implementation of the interface:

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/master/vertx-web/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/web/sstore/SessionStore.java

That uses your STOMP backend. If you're a student, this could be a interesting Google Summer of Code project.

Comment: Hi Paulo and thank you for your reply. My question is a bit different than what you suggest here. I want to enable sessions to my STOMP Server in order for connected users to be able to have some type of session (at my stomp server) and how is this possible to configure it, since the documentation does not describe any obvious way to do it